# "Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed" Error

Tags: solidity, blockchain, dapps, oracles

I am reviewing a piece of code intended for the creation of an oracle and I get the following error: "Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed"

I know it is related to the new compiler versions and I have been following some of the threads of people with similar problems in their codes but I have not just found the solution.

I hope you can help me. I leave the code snippet below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Oracle {
    Request[] requests; 
    uint currentId = 0; 
    uint minQuorum = 2; 
    uint totalOracleCount = 3; 

    struct Request{
        uint id;                            
        string urlToQuery;                  
        string attributeToFetch;            
        string agreedValue;                 
        mapping(uint => string) answers;    
        mapping(address => uint) quorum;    
    }

  
    function createRequest (
        string memory _urlToQuery,
        string memory _attributeToFetch
    )
    public
    {
        uint length = requests.push(Request(currentId, _urlToQuery, _attributeToFetch, ""));  **// The error is here**
        Request storage r = requests[length-1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem, you can use push() method for create a storage slot into your struct array about new Request struct instance to insert and then you can fill it with the input values that passed into `createRequest()` method.
I adjusted your smart code in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Oracle {
    Request[] requests; 
    uint currentId = 0; 
    uint minQuorum = 2; 
    uint totalOracleCount = 3; 

    struct Request{
        uint id;                            
        string urlToQuery;                  
        string attributeToFetch;            
        string agreedValue;                 
        mapping(uint => string) answers;    
        mapping(address => uint) quorum;    
    }

  
    function createRequest (
        string memory _urlToQuery,
        string memory _attributeToFetch,
        uint _idQuestion,
        address _addressQuorum
    )
    public
    {
        Request storage r = requests.push();
        r.id = currentId;
        r.urlToQuery = _urlToQuery;
        r.attributeToFetch = _attributeToFetch; 
        r.agreedValue = "";
        r.answers[_idQuestion] = "test";
        r.quorum[_addressQuorum] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for your reply, I just modified it as you indicated and it seems to be working perfectly.

Have a nice week :)

Comment: Accept the answer if its correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem and i have fixed it like that:

**Solidity** version i used **0.8.7**;

```
function createRequest(string memory _description, uint256 _value, address _recipient) public  restricted{
        Request storage newRequest = requests.push();
        newRequest.description = _description;
        newRequest.value = _value;
        newRequest.recipient = _recipient;
        newRequest.complete = false;
        newRequest.approvalCount = 0;
    }
```